# Custom navbar titleView won't clear previous titles before loading new ones

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

So I created a custom UINavigationItem category to be able to make a custom titleview for my navbar, but everytime I push/pop a view, **it simply adds the new title without getting rid of the old one causing the title to just be a jumble of letters**. Here's the relevant code:

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (CustomNavigationItem)
-(UIView *)titleView
{
    [self setTitleView:nil];
    UILabel *newTitleView           = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 32)];
    newTitleView.center             = CGPointMake(160, 22);
    newTitleView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];
    newTitleView.textColor          = [UIColor whiteColor];
    newTitleView.textAlignment      = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    newTitleView.text               = self.title;
    newTitleView.textAlignment      = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    return newTitleView;
}

@end
```

Comment: Anything called after return is not executed (hence is why it's called 'return'), but your biggest problem is that if that code were to execute, it would recurse infinitely.

Comment: Sorry, the statement after the return was a typo. Was that the recursion, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the old uilabel from its superview, by setting to nil it doesn't do that. That's why you are messing the letters on screen. I also do not think you are getting a recursion, because you are caling the setter, but I maybe wrong.

A quick thing you could is to assign a tag to your newest created view.

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:YourCustomEnumTag] removeFromSuperView];
// create your view....
textView.tag=YourEnumCustomTag;
```